# Why there's no compilation error in converting to std::function

Tags: c++, function, bind

Why lines with p1 and p2 compilates OK?

They have differrent types

```
#include <functional> 
#include <iostream>


void cb(int X)
{
    std::cout << X << "\n";
}

int main(void) {

 std::function<void(void)> p1 = std::bind(cb, 9);
 std::function<void(int)>  p2 = std::bind(cb, 5);    

 //p1 = p2;
}
```

If I uncomment line p1=p2 - compilation error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functional object created by `std::bind` call ignores all extra arguments. Example:

```
void f(int);

int main() {
    auto a = std::bind(f, 42);
    a();
    a(1);
    a(1, 2, 3);
}
```

You can assign such an object to `std::function` taking the same or larger number of arguments. Again, the extra arguments are going to be silently ignored.

C++11 lambdas are more efficient and the extra arguments cause a compiler error (e.g. try `auto a = []() { f(42); };`).

Comment: On *some* level that fact about `std::bind` is actually neat. On another it is super-annoying though, as the compiler can no longer warn about those extras.

Comment: I agree with your answer. `p1` and `p2` are definitely, different types. However, [this code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eLpYWbWeRSFx3J2A) questioned my understanding.

Comment: @JeJo I would expect `p1 = p2` to compile, but `p2 = p1` to fail, because you can always discard arguments, but you can't synthesize them

Comment: @Caleth Those `p1` and `p2` are from other linked code. I am removing my comment because they do not relate to this question and confuse everyone else.